# android tabhost null pointer

Tags: android, android-tabhost

i'm getting a weird null pointer exception in the last line of this code:

```
tab.addTab(newSpec);
```

this is the code:

```
private TabHost tab;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_friends);

    tab = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.activity_friends_tab);


    addTab("Chat", ChatTab.class);
}
private void addTab(String title, Class<?> cls)
{       
    TabSpec newSpec = tab.newTabSpec(title);
    newSpec.setIndicator(title);
    Intent newIntent = new Intent(this, cls);
    newSpec.setContent(newIntent);
    tab.addTab(newSpec);
}
```

can't understand why..

Comment: You really need to change that method name... the tabhost has an addTab method of its own and you are declaring another one.  Might not confuse the compiler, but it sure does me.  Or maybe it is confusing the compiler and it's the cause of your NPE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found my error:
i should have added the local activity manager and run tab.setup:

```
        LocalActivityManager mLocalActivityManager = new LocalActivityManager(
            this, false);
    mLocalActivityManager.dispatchCreate(savedInstanceState);
    tab.setup(mLocalActivityManager);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Clean your project.

Then, if the problem remains, look at activity_friends.xml and to the TabHost name, you probably used a wrong reference.

Then, if you didn't use a wrong reference, paste the whole LogCat exception here.

And then, if nothing works, just change your activity for a TabActivity and change the reference of your tab to @android:id/tabhost. Then you can reference your TabHost just by calling this.getTabHost();